# How to integrate TFS 2015 and VSTS

Tags: tfs, integration, tfs-2015

We need to synchronize several projects hosted on Visual Studio Team Services with our on-promise TFS 2015 Update 2. The ultimate goal of TFS is to have CI/CD happening within company for all external projects. However, we don't want to interrupt developers for whom using VSTS will be better choice then TFS.

However, I can't find any solution for TFS to use VSTS as a repository, though TFS can use Git. Maybe, I should look differently on this case. Does anyone know any possible solution?

Comment: Can you check http://opshub.com?

Comment: What you need to sync? Just source code?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need tools to migrate between on-premise TFS and VSTS, like:

- [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe)
- [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)

A useful [blog](https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/migration-to-vso-visual-studio-online-with-different-tools/) for your reference.

Comment: Neither of these free tools are sufficient for any serious users of TFS, and MSFT is long overdue providing such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that setting this up is going to be tricky or it's going to cost you.

The free OpsHub migration utility isn't going to help you in this scenario so you're looking at a commercial product like :

[TaskTop Sync](http://www.tasktop.com/tasktop-sync) or [OpsHub Integration Manager](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim)

but I haven't used them in this scenario so can't comment on either.

TFS Integration tools would probably do the job but you've got some work to do to get them working and it's not pretty.  I have them setup at the minute to sync Work Items from TFS 2015 to VSTS for testing purposes and it works okay.  My blog on setting them up with VSTS/2015 is [here](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/richarderwin/2016/01/27/InstallingTheTFSIntegrationToolsToMigratesyncBetweenTFS2015AndVSTS.aspx)

Would you not consider doing your CI/CD directly from VSTS rather than an on-premise TFS?  You could still have the build/release agent running on-prem and you could lock down permissions for your external devs so you control all the build and releases and any other projects.

Git would be a simpler way of merging code between VSTS and TFS2015 but that assumes you are using Git on your 2015 projects and I *believe* it would be manual process for someone to do this (someone may be able to comment on a way to make this work)